# How does Godspeed have white lightning without Philosopher's Stone?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

The 18th episode of season 5 of *The Flash* TV show is entitled "Godspeed" and Godspeed (aka August Heart) is in that episode.

He has white lightning, just like Savitar, but he is not invisible for humans and visible for speedsters. We didn't really get an explanation about how he gets his powers and the white lightning. We know that white lightning can be a result of gaining speed powers from the Philosopher's Stone.

**How did Godspeed get white lightning then?**

The Philosopher's Stone is supposed to be destroyed. And, in the comics, he has yellow lightning, making things more confusing.

Comment: IIRC, he didn't (or wasn't supposed to) have white lightning, it was...purple? Nora was checking the data at the museum and checking the different lightning of speedsters, and eventually realized that his was most close to a velocity 9 user. Haven't re-watched the episode yet.

Comment: @VBartilucci: there were two elements: first, she discovers there was never a speedster with white lightning in the Flash museum (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTXJXAVPAZ4). It seems that the museum is missing information on Savitar. Then during the second fight, Godspeed's lightning is blue. She takes this as a hint that he used Velocity 9.

Answer (score 1):

Godspeed has a flash of blue lightning in Season 5 because he first got his speed from a Velocity drug. The reason it's usually white though is because he purely uses Tachyons to get his speed

Comment: This is the start of a good answer. If you could find some sources showing how the color of the lightning is related to the drug, or tachyons, it would improve it a lot.